# Sort data within a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with ID as a primary key (also identity) and a datetimestamp column.
I need to update the table with ID's sorted per the timestamp values as shown below.
Not all the ids are present. The IDs are correct and the datetimestamps are jumbled up and need to be sorted.

Database Table with present data as -

```
id  datetimestamp
--  -----------------------
1   2013-08-08 14:08:43.560
2   2013-08-05 14:08:46.963
4   2013-08-06 14:08:53.247
5   2013-08-04 14:08:55.610
6   2013-08-03 14:08:58.543
8   2013-08-05 14:08:46.963
9   2013-08-06 14:08:53.247
10  2013-08-04 14:08:55.610
11  2013-08-03 14:08:58.543
```

Data needed as -

```
id  datetimestamp
--  -----------------------
1   2013-08-03 14:08:58.543
2   2013-08-03 14:08:58.543
4   2013-08-04 14:08:55.610
5   2013-08-04 14:08:55.610
6   2013-08-05 14:08:46.963
8   2013-08-05 14:08:46.963
9   2013-08-06 14:08:53.247
10  2013-08-06 14:08:53.247
11  2013-08-08 14:08:43.560
```

Below is script which can create the sample data -

```
create table #tmp_play
(id int identity (1,1) primary key, datetimestamp datetime)

insert into #tmp_play values (getdate());
insert into #tmp_play values (getdate()-3);
insert into #tmp_play values (getdate()-1);
insert into #tmp_play values (getdate()-2);
insert into #tmp_play values (getdate()-4);
insert into #tmp_play values (getdate()-5);

delete from #tmp_play where id = 3

insert into #tmp_play (datetimestamp) 
select datetimestamp from #tmp_play

delete from #tmp_play where id = 7
```

I tried with the below approach, but this can't be used because of the missing IDs.

```
with sorted as 
(select top 100 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY datetimestamp) as RowNum, * 
 from #tmp_play order by datetimestamp)
update t
set t.datetimestamp = s.datetimestamp
from #tmp_play t
join sorted s on t.id = s.RowNum
```

Any idea how this data can be sorted ?

Comment: Why do you need to ***STORE*** these IDs? Do you really want to update them every single time any change is made to the table? Derive the `ROW_NUMBER()` at query time.

Comment: Well, the existing data in that table is jumbled up and we want to sort it before we add more data to it taking care the process that inserts data into this table will provide correct timestamps. There is other data associated with these ids too which is also needed.

Comment: I still don't understand. If you are inserting new data, and you want a row number ordered by time stamp, what value does the existing row number give you? You're ordering by time stamp. This unnecessary rank number stored in the table is redundant and wasteful.

Comment: Lets say the Ids are correct and the datetimestamps on them are incorrect and they need to be corrected. If that makes sense ...

Comment: Downvoter - Please comment

Comment: No, it doesn't make sense, to me at least. *Why do the ID values matter?*

Comment: The ID values matter because these values go out in reports, etc and we can't get rid of them. These IDs have associated data in other columns in the same table (which I had not mentioned earlier thinking that might not be needed to understand the question) and that data is correct. The timestamps have been updated incorrectly which I am trying to fix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why does the order even matter?  It shouldn't matter to the application or the business that id 1 has a smaller/larger time value than id 2.  I understand that you are trying to fix what is deemed bad data, but this it really shouldn't impact your application.  I also agree that this sequence number is probably better derived as it doesn't offer much value.

With that said, to solve the problem at hand, you need to get two sets of sequence numbers.  1 for datetimestamp and the other for id.  You can then join on these two to update the rows.

```
;with Id_Order
AS
(
select *, id_seq = ROW_NUMBER() over(order by id)
from #tmp_play
),
Dt_Order
as
(
select *, dt_seq = ROW_NUMBER() over(order by datetimestamp asc)
from #tmp_play
)
update a
set datetimestamp = dt.datetimestamp
from Id_Order a
inner join Dt_Order dt
    on a.id_seq = dt.dt_seq
```

Comment: Thanks Adam. Yes, this is bad data which we are trying to fix. The solution works.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
update #tmp_play
set datetimestamp = s.datetimestamp
    from 
        #tmp_play
    inner join      
    (
        select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by id) rn
        from #tmp_play
    ) p
        on #tmp_play.id = p.id
    inner join 
    (
    select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by datetimestamp) rn1 from #tmp_play
    ) s
        on p.rn = s.rn1
```